# tag contents not returning in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have the following string I'm trying to extract:

```
<item>
<dc:creator><![CDATA[Chris M]]></dc:creator>
<pubDate>Tue, 06 Jun 2017 07:38:23 +0000</pubDate>
</item>
```

I'm trying to get the name Chris M and other authors with this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "lxml")
items = soup.findAll("item")
            for i in items:
                 author = i.find('dc:creator')
                 print author
```

This outputs:

```
<dc:creator></dc:creator>
```

How can I get the name contents from the tag?

Comment: Have you tried `creator` instead of `dc:creator`?

Comment: @codekaizer yes it doesn't return anything

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using Python 3 - https://repl.it/languages/python3

Specifying parser as `xml`

```
import bs4 as bs
content="""
<collection>
    <item><dc:creator><![CDATA[Chris M]]></dc:creator></item>
    <item><dc:creator><![CDATA[Harris A]]></dc:creator></item>
</collection>
"""

soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(content, 'xml')

items = soup.findAll("item")
for i in items:
   author = i.find('creator')
   print(author.string)
```

Output:

```
Chris M
Harris A
```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup recognizes CData as a subclass so you can have it check for instances of it.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, CData

>>> text = """<item>
<dc:creator><![CDATA[Chris M]]></dc:creator>
<pubDate>Tue, 06 Jun 2017 07:38:23 +0000</pubDate>
</item>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
>>> for item in soup.findAll(text=True):
        if isinstance(item, CData):
            print(item)


Chris M
```